# Serving Large Files Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-wheezy

i'm trying to setup a new gigabit debian 7 server to act as our fileserver, however i'm noticing that when i download say a 300 MB file, it downloads ~200 Kbps from the server. While the available upload is 940 Mbps.

I've setup fail2ban with GET request flood detection rules, and have mod_evasive configured for apache2. The server is also behind Cloudflare. However i have tried again via direct IP and i still notice the slow transfer rate

The server itself has 1 GB ram and duel core 3.3 Ghz CPU and 2 raid 1 SSD's.

Is there a way in which i can maximize the speed these large files will be transferred at while at the same time maintaining the current strict level of abuce and DDoS/DoS protection and cloudflare's protection?

Comment: What's the latency between server and client?

Comment: between 146 and 237 ms as i tested with more than one client.

Comment: That's a lot of latency; add in a bit of packet loss and it's entirely plausible that you'd only get 200kbps.

Comment: Have you tested other file transfer methods (ftp, sftp, rsync, samba, nfs, etc)?  If so what kind of performance are you seeing there?  Also, have you tried using `iperf` between yourself and the server to verify what kind of throughput you should be seeing?

Comment: s/should/could/

Comment: No i would consider FTP however cloudflare uses HTTP headers and cannot proxy FTP/SAMBA/NFS/Rsync. However when transfering files to the server using sftp with filezilla, i notice the speed is more like 10 Mbps.